# remove repeated headers between list items react native

Tags: react-native

I'm using @react-native-material and I've got displayed listitems, as well as headers, like this for example

```
**one**
pink 1
**one**
purple 1
**two**
blue 2
**four**
aqua 4
```

But I want to try and display it so that the headers aren't repeated like

```
**one**
pink 1
purple 1
**two**
blue 2
**four**
aqua 4
```

how could I go around doing that? This is my code. (i removed some code related with apis since it's not necessary here)

```
const App = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState<ProductType[] | []>([]);
  const [userProducts, setUserProducts] = useState<ProductType[] | []>([]);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(' ');
  const [isFocus, setIsFocus] = useState(false);
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const [productId, setProductId] = useState('');
  const [product, setProduct] = useState('');
  const [num, setNum] = useState('');
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState('');




  React.useEffect(() => {
    getProducts();
    getUserProducts();
    console.log(userProducts);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Provider>
      

        <ScrollView>
          {userProducts.length > 0 ? (
            userProducts.map(userProduct => (
              <>
                <Text>{userProduct.num}</Text>
                <ListItem
                  title={userProduct.product + ' x' + userProduct.amount}
                  onPress={async () => {
                    await deleteProduct(userProduct.product_id);
                    console.log('deleted');
                    getUserProducts();
                    ToastAndroid.show('Done', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
                  }}
                  trailing={<Text>{userProduct.num}</Text>}
                />
              </>
            ))
          ) : (
            <Text>Nothing in your list yet</Text>
          )}
        </ScrollView>
      </Provider>
    </>
  );
};
export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  dropdown: {
    height: 50,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderRadius: 8,
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without making changes to the object layout that is in userProducts,
you can create a ref variable that will keep track of previous header through each map cycle.
For Example:

```
const prevHeader = useRef('NA')

userProducts.map(userProduct => {
   if(prevHeader.current === userProduct.num){
      return <ListItem ... />
   } else {
      prevHeader.current = userProduct.num
      return (<>
         <Text>{userProduct.num}</Text>
         <ListItem ... />
       <>)
   }
}
```

The code above should be able to go into the ScrollView tag.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to generate a key value pair from userProducts where the keys are userProduct.num and the values are a list of type userProduct. Then, instead of rendering userProducts, render the new key value pair — the headers are keys and you generate a ListItem for every entry in the value array.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this with [Section List](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist), as shown in docs you will just need to rearrange the data you want to pass to the list. And you can use your ListItem in renderItem like this.

```
<SectionList
      sections={userProducts}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
      renderItem={({ item }) => 
                <ListItem
                  title={item.product + ' x' + item.amount}
                  onPress={async () => {
                    await deleteProduct(item.product_id);
                    console.log('deleted');
                    getUserProducts();
                    ToastAndroid.show('Done', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
                  }}
                  trailing={<Text>{item.num}</Text>}
                />}
      renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
        <Text>{userProduct.num}</Text>
      )}
    />
```

if you face any issue with scrolling after adding SectionList, try removing ScrollView